# Can't open Software Center

Tags: software-center, python3

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I cannot open the Ubuntu Software Center.
I keep getting this error:

```
    bash: /usr/bin/software-center: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've noticed the change when I updated python to version 3.4.1, and can't figure out how to fix this problem. Can someone explain to me what I'm failing to understand?

Comment: how do you update you python version ?

Comment: I got the file from python.org, and accessed the Python folder thru the terminal. I used the following commands './configure','make', then 'sudo make install'

Answer (score 0):

System configuration of Ubuntu written in **Python**. So It needs proper installation and compilation.

You try reinstalling **Python**, try to install and compile using the following commands,

```
# wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/Python-3.4.1.tar.xz
# tar xJf ./Python-3.4.1.tar.xz
# cd ./Python--3.4.1
# ./configure --prefix=/opt/python-3.4
# make && sudo make install
```

---

To get Python compilation components(if not exists in your s)do the following,

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the system Python with:

```
apt-get install --reinstall python2.7-minimal python-minimal
```

In future, either use Deb packages, or install your custom software to /usr/local, or - even better - compile and install everything as a normal user (without root).